# Query в SQLite

Tags: android, java, sqlite

Здравствуйте, такой вопросик. Я делаю запрос в базу данных:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
           NAME,AMOUNT}, NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
            null, null, null, null);
```

Такой запрос работает и выводит NAME из базы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить в запрос, чтобы выводились NAME из базы, но только те у которых поле AMOUNT = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот так:

```
 Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    NAME,AMOUNT}, NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%' AND " + AMOUNT + "=1", null,
    null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Спасибо ) Помогло